# Easy way to toggle between displaying piece-wise slides. Compact for preparation and expanded for presentation?

Tags: beamer

Suppose I want to use a beamer presentation with lots of piecewise slides e.g., `<1->`, `<2->`, etc. During preparation, want to toggle them all off so that the output is compact and easier to edit. Then for presentation, I'm hoping to toggle them all on by changing one line of code for presentation so that the output is expanded (i.e., one slide for each piecewise part).

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{align*}
    \onslide<1->{a &= b \\}
    \onslide<2->{b &= c \\}
    \onslide<3>{\Rightarrow \quad 
    a &= c}
\end{align*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use the `handout` option of `beamer` for this: `\documentclass[handout]{beamer}`

Comment: @dexteritas an answer? Although, I'd wager this has to be a duplicate....